# Add explanatory text to UITableView like Things.app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

Could anybody hazard a guess as to how exactly the explanatory text was added to the blank state Today screen in the [**Things**](http://culturedcode.com/things/iphone/) to-do list iPhone app? Is it a background image or a view that somehow sits in front of the `UITableView`?

Thanks in advance.

[image: A screenshot of the Things Today screen]

Comment: I just blogged about how to achieve this from scratch: https://sideprojectsoftware.com/blog/2014/08/10/explanation-table-view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a view, maybe a UILabel added and hidden and only unhidden when the number of items to be displayed in the list are 0.

Answer (score 2):

John, everytime your method `numberOfRowsInSection:` is called (considering you are using only one section), or everytime you call `reloadData` to your `UITableView`, you can do the following (considering that `numberOfRows` is the total number of rows in your `UITableView` and that `explanationView` is the UIView (that you can configure via code or interface builder) you want to show:

```
[explanationView setHidden:(numberOfRows>0)];
```