# UITableView separator lines briefly bleed through overlaid UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

Further to [this question I asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16255257/), I was able to get the explanation view appearing in front of the tableview successfully, but I now have a problem whereby the tableview's separator lines are briefly visible underneath my explanation view when the tableview first loads. This is in spite of setting the explanation view's background colour, setting it to opaque and bringing it to the front. It's just a brief flash, but it's noticeable and distracting.

Here is my code (`_explanationView` is a `UIView` instance variable that I set to `nil` in the view controller's `dealloc` method):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50.0f, 120.0f, 220.0f, 155.0f);
    _explanationView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _explanationView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _explanationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _explanationView.opaque = YES;
    _explanationView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    _explanationView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    _explanationView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    _explanationView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 180.0f, 145.0f)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    label.text = @"Explanation of this screen...";

    [_explanationView addSubview:label];
    [self.tableView addSubview:_explanationView];
}
```

I found that I had to bring the explanation view to the front in the `viewDidAppear:` method, otherwise the tableview's separator lines are permanently visible underneath.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:_explanationView];
}
```

What can I do to stop the tableview's separator lines from briefly being visible underneath my custom view?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: have you tried bringing the view to front in viewWillAppear: ?

Comment: Getting a screenshot's tricky because it only happens briefly. The separator lines are visible if bringing the view to the front in either `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9108999/1262527) which might help you.

Comment: @MariamN. That did it, thanks! If you make your comment an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108999/1262527) which indicates that handling the order of a custom subview in tableView can be done in the `layoutSubviews` method.